# Selecting records when attribute isn't there?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Say I have a collection with documents like below:

```
{
    title: "test1",
    items:
    [
        {id: 1, sub_id: 23, value:"some value"},
        {id: 2,  value:"some value"}
    ]
},
{
    title: "test2",
    items:
    [
        {id: 4, sub_id: 34, value:"blah"},
        {id: 5, sub_id: 56, value:"whatever"},
    ]
}
```

And I want to select where the attribute `sub_id` does not exist and the `id` attribute **does** exist.  If I run the query:

```
db.myCollection.find({"items.sub_id": {$exists: false}})
```

it returns the record I want (the document with title of `test1`), but when I run this query:

```
db.myCollection.find({"items.sub_id": {$exists: false}, "items.id": {$exists:true}})
```

it returns nothing.  Shouldn't my second query return the same results as the first query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your first query cannot return results from the sample that you give. The reason being that neither document has **no** array elements that do not contain a "sub_id" property. So in the first document, while the second array element is missing the property, the first does have one so the condition is in fact false. Bit of a funny thing with [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) and a false test.

So in order to make this work, you need to compare the conditions on individual array elements. This means you need the [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator:

```js
db.myCollection.find({ 
    "items": { 
        "$elemMatch": { 
            "id": { "$exists": true }, 
            "sub_id": { "$exists": false } 
        }
    }
})
```

And that correctly selects the document which has an array element where there is an "id" property but no "sub_id" property.

Due to the way that `$exists` traverses the document to match the condition, the same would apply for a single element as well, and is therefore one of the cases you use `$elemMatch` for only a single field:

```js
db.myCollection.find({ 
    "items": { 
        "$elemMatch": { 
            "sub_id": { "$exists": false } 
        }
    }
})
```

So that forces the test to be applied to the array element, where of course one element does not have the property and therefore there was at least one match and the document is returned.